# sql stored procedure in asp.net not running

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

A little background on what I'm doing.
I have a button that has a click call which takes me to this code.

```
  static public DataSet shareFiles(TransitoryRegObj argTransRegObj)
{
    string sqlString = "do_share_files"; // it's a stored procedure
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(masterConn);
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sqlString, cnn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand Comm = new SqlCommand(sqlString, cnn);
        Comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        comm.Dispose();
        cnn.Close();

        return ds;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log here should anything go wrong with anything
        //  lblmessage.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;



        if (comm != null)
            comm.Dispose();

        if (cnn != null)
            cnn.Close();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("ExceptionTable");
        dt.Columns.Add("ExceptionMessage");
        dt.Rows.Add(ex.Message);
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        return ds;
    }
}
```

The code runs fine however nothing is written to database. here is do_share_files stored procedure.

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[do_share_files] 
   --@device_id bigint, @user_id bigint, @file_name varchar(50),@full_up_path varchar(50), @upLength varchar(30)
    --,@mime_type varchar(20), @filedate varchar(30)

    AS
    BEGIN
        insert into [user_files] (device_id, user_id, original_name, original_path, up_path, content_type, up_dt)
        values (17, 30, 'test.pg', 'test.pg', 'test.pg','test.pg', '2012-11-15 03:58:06.043')


    END
```

I have static values for now since i'm just trying to get it to run to stored procedure.
I'm new to asp.net and don't know what i'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do your self a favor and stop using ADO.NET directly, it is very repetitive typing and very error prone, at the very least use something like http://abstractsql.codeplex.com  http://abstractsql.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AbsDBCommand

Comment: Or Dapper http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with this:

```
static public DataSet shareFiles(TransitoryRegObj argTransRegObj)
{
    string sqlString = "do_share_files"; // it's a stored procedure
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(masterConn))
        { 
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sqlString, cnn);
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cnn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery ();
```

To summarize:

1. `Comm` and `comm` are different commands;
2. To run the proc, you need to call `ExecuteNonQuery` or other `Execute` method.

Comment: Thanks Serge, i fixed it however it

Comment: Thanks Serge, I fixed it however it's still not working.  when i debug it; it gets to comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); and after that it jumps to Catch(Exeption ex)... any other tips?

Comment: @FelipeMartins Please post the exception details.

Comment: I looked at it and figured it out. It was just an error with the datatype was trying to put a string into date. Thanks a lot bro!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has few mistakes
1. I cant understand why you are using this line twice

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sqlString, cnn);
```

2. You didnot execute the procedure which is the main problem

```
static public DataSet shareFiles(TransitoryRegObj argTransRegObj)
{
try
{
string sqlString = "do_share_files"; // it's a stored procedure
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(masterConn);
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sqlString, cnn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
    cnn.Open();
    Comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    comm.Dispose();
    cnn.Close();

    return ds;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //something here
}
```

}

Comment: Hey Syed, Thank you for the corrections. I fixed what you told me... however when i debug it; it gets to comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); and after that it jumps to Catch(Exeption ex)... any other tips?

Comment: @FelipeMartins Please post the exception details.